How to run gRPC and HTTP server on the same port in Vert.x without port conflict?
I'm trying to run both a gRPC server and an HTTP server on the same port using Vert.x, but I'm encountering a port conflict error. Is there a way to resolve this issue and have both servers operate on the same port? Any guidance would be appreciated.
I am building a gRPC server using Vert.x. In my architecture, I plan to place a load balancer (LB) in front of the Vert.x server. The LB needs to perform health checks on the backend server using the HTTP protocol.
Therefore, I attempted to modify the code to have the gRPC server launched with VertxServerBuilder and have an HTTP server listen on the same port.
val vertxVersion = "4.5.11"
val grpcVersion = "1.58.0"
val protobufVersion = "3.21.6"
val protocVersion = protobufVersion

dependencies {
    implementation("io.vertx:vertx-grpc:$vertxVersion")
    implementation("io.vertx:vertx-grpc-server:$vertxVersion")
    implementation("io.vertx:vertx-grpc-client:$vertxVersion")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:$grpcVersion")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-stub:$grpcVersion")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-services:$grpcVersion")
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:$protobufVersion")

private static final String ANY_ADDRESS = "0.0.0.0";
private static final int GRPC_SERVER_PORT = 50051;
private static final int HTTP_SERVER_PORT = 50051;

private VertxServer grpcServer;

@Autowired
private HBaseStoreManager hbaseStoreManager;

@Autowired
private HealthStatusManager healthStatusManager;

@Override
public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {
    log.info("Starting gRPC Server...");

    // Interceptor
    TraceIdContextInterceptor traceIdContextInterceptor = new TraceIdContextInterceptor();

    // gRPC Service
    HbaseServiceHandler hbaseService = HbaseServiceHandler.of(this.hbaseStoreManager);

    grpcServer = VertxServerBuilder
        .forAddress(vertx, new InetSocketAddress(ANY_ADDRESS, GRPC_SERVER_PORT))
        .intercept(traceIdContextInterceptor)
        .addService(hbaseService)
        .addService(healthStatusManager.getHealthService())
        .handshakeTimeout(Defaults.handshakeTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .maxInboundMessageSize(Defaults.maxMessageSize)
        .maxInboundMetadataSize(Defaults.maxMetadataSize)
        .build();

    grpcServer.start(asyncResult -> {
      if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
        log.info("Listening Native gRPC on {}:{}", ANY_ADDRESS, GRPC_SERVER_PORT);
        startPromise.complete();
      } else {
        log.info("Failed to start gRPC server: " + asyncResult.cause().getMessage());
        startPromise.fail(asyncResult.cause());
      }
    });

    // HTTP server options
    HttpServerOptions serverOptions = new HttpServerOptions()
        .setUseAlpn(true)
        .setSsl(false);

    // HTTP Server (for ingress health check)
    vertx.createHttpServer(serverOptions)
        .requestHandler(
            req -> {
              if (req.uri().equals("/monitor/healthz")) {
                req.response()
                    .putHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
                    .end("OK");
              } else {
                req.response().setStatusCode(404).end();
              }
            })
        .listen(HTTP_SERVER_PORT, ar -> {
          if (ar.succeeded()) {
            log.info("HTTP server started on port {}", HTTP_SERVER_PORT);
          } else {
            log.error("Failed to start HTTP server: " + ar.cause().getMessage());
          }
        });
}

When I run the modified code, I encounter a port conflict error:
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Is it not possible to serve both HTTP and gRPC on the same port in Vert.x? If there is a solution, I would appreciate your help.
